# Como ordenar elementos de uma lista usando selection sort?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Implementei o selection sort para ordenar o texto de um .txt que transformei em lista. O problema é que ele só ordena o campo 1 e o campo 3, o campo 2 ele não ordenou, como visto no output: 10, 100, 2, 5. Onde estou errando? Obrigado desde já.

Como se trata de um trabalho de faculdade, não posso usar métodos como o sort().

```
import copy

def acharMenorValor(lista,a):
  menor_valor = lista[0][a]
  menor_index = 0
  for i in range(0,len(lista)):
    if lista[i][a] < menor_valor:
      menor_valor = lista[i][a]
      menor_index = i
  return menor_index


def selectionSort(lista,a):
  novaArray = []
  novaLista = copy.deepcopy(lista)
  for i in range(len(novaLista)):
    menor = acharMenorValor(novaLista,a)
    novaArray.append(tuple(novaLista.pop(menor)))
  print(f"Listagem dos produtos pelo campo: {a+1}")
  for i in range(len(novaArray)):
      print(novaArray[i])
  print("--------------------------------------")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    lista = []
    file = open('trabalho.txt')

    for i in range(4):
        lista.append(file.readline().split())
    print("Listagem de produtos lida do arquivo trabalho.txt")
    for i in range(len(lista)):

        print(tuple(lista[i]))

    print("--------------------------------------")

    #USANDO O SELECTION SORT
    for i in range(len(lista)-1):
        selectionSort(lista,i)
```

Output:

```
Listagem de produtos lida do arquivo trabalho.txt
('beringela', '10', '1.99')
('arroz', '5', '4.99')
('peixe', '2', '9.99')
('abacaxi', '100', '3.99')
--------------------------------------
Listagem ordenada dos produtos pelo campo: 1
('abacaxi', '100', '3.99')
('arroz', '5', '4.99')
('beringela', '10', '1.99')
('peixe', '2', '9.99')
--------------------------------------
Listagem ordenada dos produtos pelo campo: 2
('beringela', '10', '1.99')
('abacaxi', '100', '3.99')
('peixe', '2', '9.99')
('arroz', '5', '4.99')
--------------------------------------
Listagem ordenada dos produtos pelo campo: 3
('beringela', '10', '1.99')
('abacaxi', '100', '3.99')
('arroz', '5', '4.99')
('peixe', '2', '9.99')
--------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que o seu arquivo possui texto e não números. Da mesma forma que `'B'` é maior que `'AA'`, `'2'` também é considerado maior que `'11'` se eles estão sendo tratados como textos.

Uma forma simples de resolver é converter em números na hora da leitura. Ao invés de ler diretamente:

```
for i in range(4):
    lista.append(file.readline().split())
```

Faça a conversão dessa forma:

```
for i in range(4):
    linha = file.readline().split()
    linha[1] = int(linha[1])
    linha[2] = float(linha[2])
    lista.append(linha)
```